# iOS: native alternative to using CraftAR for image recognition

Tags: ios, image-processing, augmented-reality

I'd like to build an app that tells me the colour of an LED. Is this possible?

I have found **CraftAR** but before signing up I'd like to understand if there is anything that **iOS offers natively** that I could use for my simple use case.

Answer (score 0):

The [CraftAR](http://catchoom.com/documentation/image-recognition-sdk/ios-image-recognition-sdk/) service does [not use color information](http://support.catchoom.com/customer/portal/articles/1785953) of objects to be recognised.

The iOS SDK offers methods for image processing in the CoreImage library but they are intended to produce effects or apply filters in images and draw them on the screen.

You could use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) - a computer vision library - to process your images and determine the color of the LED. How difficult this is depends on your use case. You could use CraftAR to locate the LED position and OpenCV to determine the color.